# Fail to reboot with faults about bluetooth

Tags: graphics, bluetooth, reboot

This is my story: I wanted to boot Windows but I forgot to select on the grub, so it entered Ubuntu. Naturally I reboot(without logging on Ubuntu) but it halted as follows:

[image: black screen]

I had to force a shutdown and tried again, but the problem occurred still. the error information is as follows:

```
[12.771190] Bluetooth: hci0 sending Intel patch command(0xfc8e) failed (-110)
[12.771242] Bluetooth: hci0 sending frame failed(-19)
[14.786774] Bluetooth: Exiting manufacturer mode failed(-110)
```

My platform is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and my kernel is 4.10.0-42-generic. **But what I found weird is reboot worked well after I logging on Ubuntu**.
Following is the information of my device and graphic card driver:

```
finley@finley:~$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1906] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:5049]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [17aa:5048]
```

[graphic card driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrQwG.png)

Comment: Can you switch to a virtual terminal with ctrl-alt-f2 or similar ? Can you boot an old kernel ? What graphic card ?

Comment: it appeared blank screen with blinking cursor on the top-left corner after keying ctrl-alt-f2

Comment: @Panther my graphic card is Intel integrated graphics

Comment: I am guessing it is a problem with your graphics driver, but I am not sure. Perhaps boot an old kernel might be a temp fix until someone more familiar with your card can help. It would help if you identified the exact model rather than brand.

Comment: @Panther Sorry for my poor understanding to the "exact model", but I have appended some information about my devices in the post, could you check again?

Comment: No worries, that is perfect.